# How to remove spaces between each letter when writing a dictionary to a csv using csv.writer

Tags: python, csv, csvwriter

I've been trying to make a csv reader that will read a large data set, group the same events together, and count up how many times those events happened. I'm using nested dictionaries to do it.

For some reason the formatting is wrong and it keeps adding spaces between every single character in the [string](https://i.imgur.com/9jV8C9X.png) I'm writing.

Does anyone know how to remove it?

I've tried a few other things I've seen on here such as changing write to 'wb' and adding a new line argument, but I couldn't get any of them to work.

```
with open(r'Redacted', 'w') as reportCSV:
    writer = csv.writer(reportCSV, delimiter=' ')
    for dates, info in dict.items():
        for key in info:
            writer.writerow(dates + ':' + key + ':' + str(info[key]))
```

Comment: Please include input data that is a string as text directly in the question, not by linking to an external site that contains an image.

Comment: `delimiter=' '` suspiciously looks like inserting spaces where you don't want them.

Comment: Are you trying to use `":"` as the delimiter? It looks like you've built a string with `dates + ':' + key + ':' + str(info[key])` which, combined with the `delimiter=` `` would do just what you see. So, what do you want a single row to look like? Is it 3 columns, separated by ":"?

Comment: Perhaps you could `print(repr(dates + ':' + key + ':' + str(info[key]))` for a single row to show what you are tyring to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow` iterates its `row` parameter, converts it to a string, applies any needed escapes and uses `delimiter` as the separator. In your case, it appears as though `dates + ':' + key + ':' + str(info[key])` is a string. `writerow` iterates it character by character and inserts the `' '` delimiter.

It appears that you want 3 semi-colon separated columns. That third column could iterated directly via a second `.items()` call. Put them in a list for the writer.

```
with open(r'Redacted', 'w') as reportCSV:
    writer = csv.writer(reportCSV, delimiter=':')
    for dates, info in dict.items():
        for key, value in info.items():
            writer.writerow([dates, key, value])
```

Comment: That also sticks an empty row between everything now

Comment: I don't see anything here that would insert newlines. You could try `open(r'Redacted', 'w', end ='')`. It would be interesting to get a few lines of the raw CSV file.